# How to access root directory folder from public_html folder through the web using cPanel?

Tags: cpanel, subdirectory, folder

I am able to create folders in my `root` directory using cPanel.  When I do so I would like to be able to access them from  the `public_html` so that they are available on my website.   However, I don't see any way of doing so.

Are folders at the root level actually accessible from `public_html` folder?   If I want to make them accessible, then how to do that?

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do here? It is not very clear. Maybe provide an example?

Comment: In the filemanager of c panel we saw a lots of folder, one of them is public_html where we put our file to run publicly to cloud. but if i want to browse the other folder from my cloud folder[public_html] then how can i do?

Comment: "browse the other folder from my cloud" - still not sure what you mean? Like you said yourself, only the contents of the `public_html` folder is _public_ (ie. browsable over HTTP). Everything else, outside of the `public_html` folder, is not accessible over HTTP. Directories outside of the `public_html` folder are only available to your server-side code.

Comment: so from public_html i can't browse any of them?

Comment: Well, like I say, I'm not sure exactly what you mean, but the answer would seem to be "no". However, if you provide an example, we can perhaps clarify what you mean. A statement like "access it from my public_html folder" doesn't really make sense. It's not clear how you are accessing your files, HTTP, FTP, etc.?

Comment: I added the picture of my c panel filemanager, please check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want something to be accessible publicly on the web, you should put it in the `public_html` folder.   You can create folders within `public_html` as well.

There is no functionality in cPanel for publicly browsing files outside of `public_html`.   That is a security feature.   Many items in the root folder should not be public.   There are passwords stored in *.htpasswds*.  Your server logs might have sensitive details about your users.   Anything that you want to be visible on your site should go in the place that is designated for that.

Comment: If permissions allow, the OP can possibly create a symlink to the desired directory. I have done this in the past without issues. Of course, permissions can be set for the target directory to make this happen. Still, your advice to create the directory in the web root is best, or course.